# param tag giving me a parsing error

Tags: webmatrix

this simple html5 example gives me an 'element param cannot be nested inside of element body'
error when using webmatrix 3 as a parser:

```
<body>
<object id = "a">
<param name = "b" id = "c">
</object>
</body>
```

Why the error, and what is another program I could use to check the syntax?

Comment: Thanks to all... I can ignore the warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the webmatrix3 parser. It's valid HTML5:

- [W3 param tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_param.asp)
- [W3 valid global attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

id is not an approved attribute. Try using the approved attributes for the object element as listed here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_param.asp

I hope that helps.